# what is an illegal invocation typeerror in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code that raises an alert if it's being run in the browser, but which I don't want to raise alerts when I run unit tests.

I tried to solve this by having a line

```
if( allowAlerts === false ){
    alert = console.log;
}
```

but when I then run

```
alert("This bad thing happened");
```

I get back

```
TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

directly reassigning alert was a kludgey solution, and I can easily solve the problem in other ways, but I've never come across an illegal invocation error before and was hoping someone could explain what it means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `console.log` function needs its calling context to be the console.

Use

```
alert = console.log.bind(console);
```

Or if you want to be compatible with old IE :

```
alert = function(){ console.log.apply(console, arguments) };
```

Comment: Or just shim `bind` :)

Comment: @AdamRackis As you can't make a complete shim of bind, I'm vary of this solution. Either I don't care for old browsers, or I avoid `shim` completely.

Comment: How do you mean?  Are you mixing up the bind shim with Object.create??  Doesn't the bind shim simulate setting `this` and curry parameters as the real thing does?

Comment: @AdamRackis Look at bind at the MDN, it lists the limits of what a shim can do.